# Sum weights based on other rows values

Tags: sql

i'm looking for a query to sum the weights (from the first row -> q17), for every row (every question), but based on the answers of other questions. the idea is to leave out the value from the sum, if the answer does not have a value within other questions.

example

```
q17 5   5   4   3   5   5   4   5   =   36  for q17
q18 4   2   3   2   5   4   1   4   =   36  for q18
q19 5   2   4   2   5   4   1   4   =   36  for q19
q20 4   2   5   3   5   4   1   4   =   36  for q20
q21 4       5   3   5   5   1       =   26  for q21
q22 4   2   4   2   4   4   1   4   =   36  for q22
q23 4   1   4   3   5   4   1   4   =   36  for q23
q24 4   1   4   1   5   3   1   4   =   36  for q24
q25 5   2   4   3   5   4   1   4   =   36  for q25
q26 5   4   5   3   5   5   5   5   =   36  for q26
q27 5   4   4   1   5   4   1   4   =   36  for q27
q28 4   1   5   2   5   5   1   4   =   36  for q28
q29 5   5   5   4   5   4   5   5   =   36  for q29
q30 4   2   3   2   5   4   1   4   =   36  for q30
q31 4   3   4   4   5   4   1   5   =   36  for q31
q32 4   1   4   1   5   4   1   4   =   36  for q32
```

the weights are at q17. and i need to calculate the weights for every question. but where a question isn't answered, i don't need to sum into the weights.

don't take q18-32 as values, just take them only as true/false if it has a value or not for the question then sum the weights from q17 based on this for every q.

the data is the following

```
Q   A
17  5
18  4
19  5
20  4
21  4
22  4
23  4
24  4
25  5
26  5
27  5
28  4
29  5
30  4
31  4
32  4
17  5
18  2
19  2
20  2
22  2
23  1
24  1
25  2
26  4
27  4
28  1
29  5
30  2
31  3
32  1
17  4
18  3
19  4
20  5
21  5
22  4
23  4
24  4
25  4
26  5
27  4
28  5
29  5
30  3
31  4
32  4
17  3
18  2
19  2
20  3
21  3
22  2
23  3
24  1
25  3
26  3
27  1
28  2
29  4
30  2
31  4
32  1
17  5
18  5
19  5
20  5
21  5
22  4
23  5
24  5
25  5
26  5
27  5
28  5
29  5
30  5
31  5
32  5
17  5
18  4
19  4
20  4
21  5
22  4
23  4
24  3
25  4
26  5
27  4
28  5
29  4
30  4
31  4
32  4
17  4
18  1
19  1
20  1
21  1
22  1
23  1
24  1
25  1
26  5
27  1
28  1
29  5
30  1
31  1
32  1
17  5
18  4
19  4
20  4
22  4
23  4
24  4
25  4
26  5
27  4
28  4
29  5
30  4
31  5
32  4
```

Comment: can you show us an actual example of the sample data rather than saying what it is not like?

Comment: edited with the data in

Comment: are you wanting every value in a column each or is just the total at the end fine?

Comment: not sure what you mean. i would need the result as Q17 -> 36, Q18 -> 36, Q19 -> 36, Q20 -> 36, Q21 -> 26 (because of the 2 null values), Q22 -> 36 ... etc.

Comment: Q17 are the weights, i need the sum (weights -> from Q17) for every question (Q18-32). only Q21 will be different because it has 2 missing values.

Comment: don't take q18-32 as values, just take only if it has a value then sum the weights from q17.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you require:

```
SELECT   'q'+CAST(Q AS nvarchar(4)) AS Q,
         CAST(SUM(A) AS NVARCHAR(4)) + ' total for q' + CAST(Q AS NVARCHAR(4)) AS A
FROM     tbl
GROUP BY Q
```

With a sample [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/75b80/2)

Output:

```
Q   A
q17 36 total for q17
q18 25 total for q18
q19 27 total for q19
q20 28 total for q20
q21 23 total for q21
q22 25 total for q22
q23 26 total for q23
q24 23 total for q24
q25 28 total for q25
q26 37 total for q26
q27 28 total for q27
q28 27 total for q28
q29 38 total for q29
q30 25 total for q30
q31 30 total for q31
q32 24 total for q32
```

Comment: nope, it should be 36 for all q's, except q21, where should be 26.

Comment: then you have given incorrect data as I have used all of what you gave

Comment: the data is fine, just the query isn't doing what i would need. i did the same as you, but it's not correct. the weights are at q17. and i need to calculate the weights for every question. but where a question isn't answered, i don't need to sum the weights. hope is clearer now.

Comment: @PopLevente please put the update on your question. It is not the answerer's task to ask you for clarification. Ty.

Comment: @AndyK - was already there, but i extended now. unfortunately i don't know a better way to explain. if you know a better way, please tell and i will edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`col0` varchar(3),
     `col1` int,
     `col2` int, 
     `col3` int, 
     `col4` int, 
     `col5` int, 
     `col6` int,
     `col7` int, 
     `col8` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`col0`, `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`, `col6`, `col7`, `col8`)
VALUES
    ('q17', 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5),
    ('q18', 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 4),
    ('q19', 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 4, 1, 4),
    ('q20', 4, 2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 1, 4),
    ('q21', 4, NULL, 5, 3, 5, 5, 1, Null),
    ('q22', 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4),
    ('q23', 4, 1, 4, 3, 5, 4, 1, 4),
    ('q24', 4, 1, 4, 1, 5, 3, 1, 4),
    ('q25', 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 1, 4),
    ('q26', 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5),
    ('q27', 5, 4, 4, 1, 5, 4, 1, 4),
    ('q28', 4, 1, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1, 4),
    ('q29', 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5),
    ('q30', 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 4),
    ('q31', 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 1, 5),
    ('q32', 4, 1, 4, 1, 5, 4, 1, 4)
;


SELECT *, 
Concat('= ',(IFNULL(`Col1`,0)+ 
             IFNULL(`Col2`,0)+ 
             IFNULL(`Col3`,0)+ 
             IFNULL(`Col4`,0)+ 
             IFNULL(`Col5`,0)+ 
             IFNULL(`Col6`,0)+ 
             IFNULL(`Col7`,0)+ 
             IFNULL(`Col8`,0)),' For ',Col0) As Result from Table1
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8dcff2/2

Comment: not quite. your query sums the rows, but i need to sum row 1, based on the other rows, for every question. every question should have sum 36, except q21, which should have 26, because 2 answers are missing (null)